# cmake error suitesparseconfig.cmake

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i've got an error when i compiled `mcptam`.

After `catkin_make`, then i had message like this

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSUITESPARSE.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "SUITESPARSE", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SUITESPARSE" with
  any of the following names:

    SUITESPARSEConfig.cmake
    suitesparse-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SUITESPARSE" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SUITESPARSE_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SUITESPARSE" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

please help me guys. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224475/cmake-error-suitesparseconfig.cmake/) by [jamni](https://answers.ros.org/users/25658/jamni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're missing the dependency SUITESPARSE in your environment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0